# Как обратиться к соседнему элементу через this, на jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько блоков с одинаковыми классами. В блоке кнопка и модалка. При клике на кнопку навешиваем класс на модалку этого блока. 
Вроде всё просто, но что-то не получается...
В примере пробую через siblings(), так же пробовал через find(). Класс не навешивается. Подскажите что не так делаю.

```js
$('.button').on('click', () => { 
    $(this).siblings('.modal').addClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
}

.button { cursor: pointer;}
.modal {
  display: none;
}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <span class="button">Кнопка</span>
  <p class="modal">Модалка</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="button">Кнопка</span>
  <p class="modal">Модалка</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в стрелочной функции:

> Стрелочные функции не содержат собственный контекст this, а используют значение this окружающего контекста

[источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Так что надо писать так:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).siblings('.modal').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid;
  
}

.button { cursor: pointer;}
.modal {
  display: none;
}

.modal.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <span class="button">Кнопка</span>
  <p class="modal">Модалка</p>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="button">Кнопка</span>
  <p class="modal">Модалка</p>
</div>
```